# Client is both the host and the client while host is only the host - Unity Relay

Tags: unity-game-engine, multiplayer

When placing this conditional in `Update()` of the player script, the host shows:
"IsClient 0",

and the client shows both: "IsClient 0", "IsClient 1":

```
if (IsClient)
    {
        Debug.Log("IsClient " + OwnerClientId);
    }
```

Any ideas why the client is both the host and the client at the same time?